# addView dynamically can not get measuredHeight in android

Tags: android

I try to encapulate a custom listView with head and footer.here is the description
of my problem.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<com.example.pj.news_demo.widget.WrapperView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_msg_wrapper_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/msg_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff34ff"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />
</com.example.pj.news_demo.widget.WrapperView>
```

Code above is my ui,WrapperView can be treated as a container,and RecycleView is the initial content.In the outside,some interface will be provided for the user ,handling the WrapperView,like addHeaderView() and addFooterView().

So,here is the strange thing.
In the fragment,i got WrapperView,try to add header and footer for it.

```
  mWrapperView.addHeaderView(new RefreshHeader(getContext()));
  mWrapperView.addFooterView(new RefreshFooter(getContext()));
```

In the wrapper,i try to get children's measuredHeght,header,RecycleView and footer.

I will show you the detail of addHeaderView() and addFooterView()

```
    public void addHeaderView(RefreshHeader headerView) {
    if (headerView == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("FooterView must not be null");
    }
    ViewUtil.removeViewFromParent(headerView);
    mHeaderView = headerView;
    addView(mHeaderView, 0); *//header will be the first child*
    if (mHeaderView instanceof IHeaderCallback) {
        mHeaderCallback = (IHeaderCallback) mHeaderView;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("HeadView must implement IHeaderCallback interface");
    }
}

  public void addFooterView(RefreshFooter footerView) {
    if (footerView == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("FooterView must not be null");
    }
    ViewUtil.removeViewFromParent(footerView);
    mFooterView = footerView;
    Log.i(TAG, "FooterView添加之前的子孩子数量:" + getChildCount());
    addView(footerView,getChildCount()); *//footer will be the last child*
    if (mFooterView instanceof IFooterCallback) {
        mIFooterCallback = (IFooterCallback) footerView;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("FooterView must implement IFooterCallback interface");
    }

}
```

I override WrapperView's onMeasure function,try to get children's name and  measuredHeight,here is the code.

```
    @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        Log.i(TAG, "child---" + getChildAt(i).getClass().getCanonicalName() + "---height:" + getChildAt(i).getMeasuredHeight() + "\n");
    }
}
```

And,here is the result:
   child---com.example.pj.news_demo.widget.RefreshHeader---height:210

child---android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView---height:1323

child---com.example.pj.news_demo.widget.RefreshFooter---height:0

I can not get footerView's measuredHeight.

Util this problem solved,i can not move a step further.I hope you guys can give me some suggestions.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is because the view did not get created when your getMeasuredHeight was executed.

Use ViewTreeObserver on your WrapperView.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = mWrapperView.getViewTreeObserver();

vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {                

            //get your height here and do your stuff
        }
    });
```

Comment: i get the measureHeight in onMeasure method
it has been measured actually.

Comment: You are not getting the third child Height i.e. footer view on your onMeasure, is that right?

Comment: Perform the same code you are doing at onMeasure and check.

Comment: yes,i get footerView's height in onMeasure method.You can review my code above.

Comment: then what is actually issue?
I can see you have put following in your question.

**child---com.example.pj.news_demo.widget.RefreshFooter---height:0

I can not get footerView's measuredHeight.**

As you said in comment you are getting height of footerView then what is the issue?

Comment: footView's height is 0,and headView's height is normal.
The issue is why footView's height is 0(because headView is normal)

Comment: that is why I told to use my solution. Drawing of view take some time. When you call for footView's height it hasn't been drawn yet. That is why you are getting as 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is not final width and height because it not already created and calculate size. Let try

```
int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
```

Comment: what confuse me is that  i can get header's measuredHeight,how cannot get footer's height.I get what you want to say,but i overwrite WrapperView‘s onMeasure method,and the footer is actually measured,as log showed in the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,problem has been solved by myself,it is really a little mistake.
so,here is the thing.

[image]